# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WindowsFormsAppForAPI.employeeData>' to 'string'

Tags: c#, api

I have created web api EmployeeService which contains database "employeeData" and want to fetch the data through windows form. But it is giving error CS0029.The code causing error is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64511/");
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Employee").Result;
    string emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<employeeData>>().Result;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = emp;
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<employeeData> emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<employeeData>>().Result;`

Comment: `string emp` Why are you using `string`?

Answer (score 1):

Your right hand side of the expression is returning object of type `IEnumerable<employeeData>` while on left hand side you say that i expect `string` object which ofcourse compiler does not likes. It should be :

```
IEnumerable<employeeData> emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<employeeData>>().Result;
```

or you can use `var` which will take care of figuring out the correct type for you by evaluating the right hand side:

```
var emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<employeeData>>().Result;
```